# How to only update an sql table column if a variable is not empty with php?

Tags: php, sql

I am getting my variables from form fields using php :

```
    $url=$_POST['url'];
    $tags=$_POST['tags'];
    $skillArea=$_POST['skill_area'];
    $description=$_POST['description'];
    $slideshowImageFileName=($_FILES['imageNameSlideshow']['name']);
```

But when I run my sql insert query, I get an error if one of the variables is empty, so I have taken to write if statements to deal with this to rewrite the query string, but surely, that's not the answer?  It seems very messy

```
if(empty($slideshowImageFileName)){

        $query1="INSERT INTO portfolio (item_name,image_path,description,url) VALUES('$itemName','$imageFileName','$description','$url')"; 

    }else{

        $query1="INSERT INTO portfolio (item_name,image_path,description,url,slideshow_image_path) VALUES('$itemName','$imageFileName','$description','$url','$slideshowImageFileName')"; 
    }
```

Comment: Do you initialise the variables to make them empty before assigning a value? Also, what are your database constraints? What error do you get?

Comment: no I don't insitalise them, they just are as they are above.  I get the error ion syntax, outputting the query is comes out as INSERT INTO tags (portfolio_item_id, html5, javascript) VALUES(29,, 1) so the middle value is empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you are looking for something like this:

```
$slideshowImageFileName = (isset($_FILES['imageNameSlideshow']['name']) && !empty($_FILES['imageNameSlideshow']['name'])) ? $_FILES['imageNameSlideshow']['name'] : NULL;
```

This will check if the name of the slideshowimage is set and not empty. if it is NULL will be assigned to the variable, if its correct the value will be assigned.

You could replace NULL with "" if you want an empty string to be added.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the value of $slideshowImageFileName to empty string or a single space as your database table will accept, and use the second query always.

```
if(empty($slideshowImageFileName)){
$slideshowImageFileName = "";
}

$query1="INSERT INTO portfolio (item_name,image_path,description,url,slideshow_image_path) VALUES('$itemName','$imageFileName','$description','$url','$slideshowImageFileName')";
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a few options to this.

Simplest one is to make sure the variables are always set, even if not passed through:

```
//Set up your database connection as normal, check errors etc.
$db = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$db);

$url = isset($_POST['url']) ? mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['url']) : "";
$tags= isset($_POST['tags']) ? mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['tags']) : "";
```

Escaping data is good practice :) In your INSERT query you'll still need to wrap the values in quotes, or you could do that in the above code as per your preference.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php

Comment: i get an error with that code :  Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given

Comment: Sorry, my bad - you need to set the first parameter as your database connection as defined with mysqli_connect() - I'll edit the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am agreed with Mr. Ray. But there is another solution apart from that. Probably slideshow_image_path field on the table doesn't allow null. So you may change the attribute by allowing null and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably construct a builder if I'm sure I'll get a lot of optional data.

Like this:

```
$acceptedKeys = array
  ('item_name', 
   'image_path',
   'description', 
   'url',
   'slideshow_image_path');
$inserts = array();

foreach($_GET as $key => $var) {
  if(in_array($key, $acceptedKeys)) {
    // clean and validate your keys here!
    $inserts[$key] = $var;
  }
}

$customKeys = implode(array_keys($inserts), ',');
$customValues = implode($inserts, ',');

$query = "INSERT INTO portfolio ($customKeys) VALUES($customValues)";
```